# How to Exclude nodes from Path in Cypher?

Tags: java, graph, neo4j, cypher

I'm stuck writing a Cypher query that would allow me to find all nodes which their code are NOT included in a given list. I've tried searching for pattern negation, node negation, exclude in path with no success.

**Let's assume I have a list of codes (even though this list one has 1 element): ["1V2ZG"]**

I'd like to build a Cypher query that would return every child of ARNOG node which is NOT in the above list.

This is the starting graph:

[image]

The graph response I want:

[image]

The query I'm using is returning all nodes which is not what I want:

```
MATCH 
(excl:Client)<-[:PARENT_OF*]-(n:Client:Group),
path=(b:BaseHierarchy)-[:INCLUDES]->(n)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(inc:Client) 

WHERE excl.code IN ['1V2ZG']  AND n.code = 'ARNOG' 
WITH b,
nodes(path) as nodes, relationships(path) as relationships 
RETURN b,
apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(collect(relationships))) as relationships,
apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(collect(nodes))) as nodes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
MATCH path=(b:BaseHierarchy)-[:INCLUDES]->(n)-[:PARENT_OF*]->(inc:Client) 
WHERE n.code = 'ARNOG' AND 
      NONE(node IN nodes(path) WHERE node.code IN ['1V2ZG'])
WITH b, nodes(path) AS nodes, relationships(path) AS relationships 
RETURN b,
       apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(collect(relationships))) as relationships,
       apoc.coll.toSet(apoc.coll.flatten(collect(nodes))) as nodes;
```

?